# Store JS Object and return him - Nodejs addon

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I am only trying to build a addon that only receives any object and return them back.

Server:

```
var is_object = addon.return_object(previous_object);
```

Addon:

```
void return_object(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    Local<Object> obj = Object::"From args"; //The missing part

    args->GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is:

```
Local<Object> obj = args[arg_value]->ToObject();
```